# How to use AnimeGAN in spyder

Tags: python, spyder

I am interested in AnimeGAN. It can turn some real photos into anime styles.

I found some tutorial in youtube. But none of them is using Spyder to perform the task of turnning some real photos into anime styles.

I am a newbie of programming and love Spyder very much.

Can anybody teaches my how to use AnimeGAN in spyder , please?

Comment: Can you please give a link to the version of AnimeGAN you are using, perhaps also a link for the YouTube video you reference.

Comment: https://github.com/bryandlee/animegan2-pytorch
Also,
https://github.com/TachibanaYoshino/AnimeGANv2
I hope the above two links helps.

Comment: can you please add code you tried running and other things you tried and tell us what worked and what didn't?